# Missing libraries in _PublishedWebsites folder

Tags: build, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, roslyn

I created a simple web application with VS2015. Also, I made a build which, as per default behavior specified in the linked msbuild file, places my website inside _PublishedWebsites folder in the drop location.
What I do see if I try to publish my website is that the roslyn folder in the bin directory is missing together with it's content.
Actually the content is there but is inside the bin directory itself.
For now I use a workaround and in postbuild step, I do copy the folder in question.

```
xcopy /s /y /R "$(OutDir)roslyn\*.*" "$(WebProjectOutputDir)\bin\roslyn"
```

Why of not maintaining the structure in the bin folder?
Is there anything that I'm missing in order to have this fixed?

EDIT:
It seems that this problem is not manifesting itself if the nuget package restore is in the place. In case the package restore is performed, the problem doesn't persist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that this problem is not manifesting itself if the nuget package restore is in the place. In case the package restore is performed, the problem doesn't persist.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the nuget package resotre is in the place"... what nuget package? How did you achieve a solution?